# nextjs/emailjs can't find path for image attachment

Tags: next.js

I'm using NextJS and emailJS (npm package, not to be confused with emailjs.com service) to send email with image attachment. I can't seem to figure out why, but whenever I try to attach a file while sending email, I get the error:
Error: image.jpeg does not exist

I have a file image.jpeg in /public/image.jpeg, I've tried these combinations:

```
/image.jpeg
/public/image.jpeg
../../public/image.jpg (relative path from emailjs file)
localhost:3000/image.jpeg
Also tried to pull one off of internet, just: www.url.com/images/image.jpeg
```

None of these seem to work

I'm constructing my message this way:

```
const message = { ... 
attachment: [ {data: ..., alternative: true},
 { path: '/image.jpeg', type: 'image/jpeg', name: 'image.jpeg' }, ], 
};
```

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One major thing I've missed to say was that I'm using this in nextJS /api folder which I suppose handles paths a little different.

Answer:
Need to import "path" and use this:

```
const publicDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'public');
```

to get the actual path of public folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is located in the /public directory, you should use the following value for the path property:

```
path: '/public/image.jpeg'
```

This should allow you to attach the file to your email message.

Comment: That was my thought as well. However, I tried this, I triple checked that "image.jpeg" exists in /public folder, and yet I receive: `unhandledRejection: Error: /public/image.jpeg does not exist`

Comment: Try logging the value of the path field in the attachment object to see what file path is being used.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how can I log it? 'Path' is a property which value I need to enter, not sure how can I log it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: To log the value of the path property, use console.log(message.attachment[1].path).